# DataTable filter the filter based on displayed data

Tags: javascript, filter, datatables

From what I understand, the filter part of DataTable is a plugin, the brief documentation for which is here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/wikis/ColumnFilter.wiki

What I would like to accomplish is when the user filters the data, I want the filter dropdown options to change based on whats available in the current dataset. For example, if I filter the "Food type" to be "Meat", I don't want to see vegetables or fruit in the "Food" filter, only different kinds of meat. If I picked "Vegetables" in the "Food type" filter, then I would only see vegetables, such as "Potatoes", in the "Food" filter.

Specific requirements:

- the filters section must be separate from the table
- on initial load - show no "food" options in "food" filter
- once "Food type" selection changes - update "food" filter with options applicable to that "food type". likely use "search:applied". if the "food type" is set to the default "all food" type, show no "food" in "food" filter. make sure the table gets redrawn when the "food" is selected for filtering.
- do not update "food" filter list when a "food" is selected, unless to change the selected "food" (if thats not done automatically already)

Currently, the filter seems to be set only at the beginning when the page is initialized. The columnFilter option does allow one to set specific values to the filters, but I believe this only once on page load. The problem with redrawing the filter this way will likely be saving the user selections for the filters.

Another way I can think of is updating the filter option lists in a separate JavaScript function whenever the filter selection is changed. This will involve parsing the data from the filtered data-set using this functionality:

```
table.on('search.dt', function() {
    //number of filtered rows
    console.log(table.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).nodes().length);
    //filtered rows data as arrays
    console.log(table.rows( { filter : 'applied'} ).data());                                  
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h4wrmfx3/

I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this, perhaps with the use of built in DataTables functionality.

Comment: Hi, you're looking in the wrong place for documentation - there's tons on the official site - https://datatables.net/. Also, take a look at YADCF (http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html) - this extends the filtering offered by DataTables. If you look at that example, the code is on the page further down, you'll see it searches on mood, which groups various values together. That should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: @colin0117 Thanks! I'll check out YADCF.

Comment: @colin0117 So you propose that I solve my problem by creating a custom YADCF filter function? I don't see any other ways in the documentation to turn on this sort of feature.

Comment: You can do a lot within DataTables. These examples, http://live.datatables.net/yafazeme/2/edit and https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html, create dropdowns. If you're strong at JS, you could do something like those, within a DataTables initComplete callback if it's a DOM dataset or its xhr event trigger if Ajax sourced data, and create your own controls. I haven't used YADCF, but I know it's well regarded and extends DataTables filtering capabilities. I know this a "here's how to do it" answer, but I hope it gives you awareness of the options.

Comment: @colin0117 I've tried to implement what I wanted with YADCF, but the cumulative_filtering option doesn't quite do what I need. I'll look into the other options you've mentioned. So far I'm just trying to use the API and JavaScript to achieve the requirements. I've updated the post with the detailed description of the requirements at hand. 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html was indeed very helpful as a base.